# what binaries do i need to get SP reports working on sharepoint 2010

Tags: reporting-services

I am configuring the report services on my sql server and am wondering what sharepoint binaries I need to install on the server to get the reports up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have SSRS, you'll need to add it as a SharePoint Service and also configure your SQL Server for Analysis services.

Below url will guide you through all the process (I followed it to configure mine a while back).

http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2012/07/setting-up-reporting-services-2012-with-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: I'm using sharepoint 2010 and this article is about 2013?

Comment: This works for 2010 as well. Did it for 2010 also